# Cannot remember the original head

Tags: git, head

After I executed lots of checkout operations, I could not remember which was the original HEAD before these checkouts. How can I find back the HEAD?

Comment: it's just above the neck. please edit your title and perhaps elaborate a little

Answer (score 5):

Use `git reflog` to find out why and to what commit HEAD was changed.

Comment: Thanks, I have not had a reason to learn the `git reflog` command before.

Answer (score -1):

A git repository is a tree of commits with some labels attached to some of the commits.  These labels are a way of naming specific branches of the tree.  By default, initially, there are two labels `master` and `HEAD`.  `master` indicates the main branch of the tree, while `HEAD' is the label that indicates which commit you are currently on in the tree of commits.

With that said, `HEAD` is always where you are, when you `git checkout` you are moving `HEAD` from one commit to another on the tree.

As far as I know, there is no tracking of how the `HEAD` label moves within the tree.

However, if you want to see more clearly where you are in the entire tree, the `git log` command can show you this well -- although it can take some research to know what options will show you just what you want to see.

A few examples of `git log` commands I use often are below, perhaps they will help you find your way around.  Each lists the commits from with child commits above parent commits

- This one lists all the commits on the branch you are currently on, decorated with the names of the branches and a graph on the left that shows how the commits relate to each other.

  `git log --oneline --decorate=short --graph`
- Same as the above, but shows all commits in the tree connected to where you are.

  `git log --oneline --decorate=short --graph --all`
- Here is one that shows just those commits that have been labeled

  `git log --oneline --decorate=short --simplify-by-decoration --graph --all`

There is another sort of label, `git tag`.  A `tag` can be created to mark a commit that is important to you for some reason.  Once you find the commit your looking for, consider putting a `tag` on it so you can find it easily again.

If this doesn't help you find your way around, post more details of your specific issue.

Comment: "As far as I know, there is no tracking of how the HEAD label moves within the tree." -> `git reflog` is it.

Comment: That is a very long, very incorrect answer when a one-word answer would have sufficed: "reflog".

Comment: As I said "As far as I know ...".  Can't know everything, and to think, it only cost me a down vote to learn it. :p